# variable js no se muestra en sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, ajax, sweetalert2

Tengo una función que envía datos por `AJAX` y recibe una respuesta, la idea era que las respuestas se fueran concatenando a una variable llamada `resp`, que si se imprime al completarse el `AJAX` pero no en la alerta de `sweetalert`. Tengo entendido que al crear la variable al inicio de la función, puede ser llamada en cualquier momento dentro de esa función, ¿o me equivoco?

```js
    function actualiza(){
        var resp = '';
        $("input:checked").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            datos = new FormData();
            datos.append('id', id);
            $.ajax({
                        url: "apruebaInci.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: datos,
                        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                        contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            $('#loading').show();
                            $('.continuar').attr('disabled','disabled');
                        },
                        complete: function(){
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('.continuar').removeAttr('disabled');
                            console.log('final'+resp);//aqui si se imprime
                        },
                        success: function(r){
                            resp = resp + r;
                          console.log(resp);//aqui si se imprime
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Error al actualizar.');
                        }
                      });
                      
                
        });
        Swal.fire({ //https://sweetalert2.github.io/
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Actualización incidentes',
            text: resp+'aaaaaa' ,//aqui no se imprime nada, solo el 'aaaaaa'
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            confirmButtonText: 'ACEPTAR',
            allowOutsideClick: true //cerrar popup al clickear fuera del este

        }).then((resultado) => {
            if (resultado.isConfirmed) {
               location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Me botaron en contra no se por qué. ¿Pudiste resolverlo o es otra cosa?

Comment: así veo y no, es otra cosa.

Comment: Te dejé una explicación más extensa, en verdad de eso se trata, si necesitas más ayuda no hay problema y actualiza el código luego de realizar los cambios aconsejados si tu problema persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Después de volver a leer tu pregunta insisto que tu problema es la petición asíncrona.

Tu AJAX imprime sin problemas los valores de `resp`, pero en el contexto de ejecución, `Swal.fire` recibe `resp=""`. En tu código, `resp` siempre estará vacío en `Swal.fire`.

¿Por qué? Proceso asíncrono. AJAX envía una solicitud que se maneja fuera del `stack` de Javascript, eso significa:

1. Lanzas la función `actualiza()`, `var resp` es igual a una cadena vacía, tal y como la declararas.
2. `$.ajax` es llamado, sin embargo, al ser una petición asíncrona, sale del `stack` y se ejecuta en paralelo.
3. Cuando `$.ajax` sale del stack de ejecución, se llama `Swal.fire`. Aquí, `resp` es todavía igual a un string vacío. Se resuelve todo y se dispara la respuesta con `resp=""`, entonces el texto, como bien dices, no imprime nada.
4. Una vez que se resuelva la llamada asíncrona con `$.ajax`, esta vuelve al stack de ejecución y modifica el valor de `resp`.

Coméntame si te queda claro como se comporta tu código, te recomiendo leer documentación sobre el `event loop` de Javascript. Igualmente, investiga qué resuelven los Callbacks y las promesas. Con esos conceptos claros, entenderás inmediatamente a qué me refiero y tu problema se resolverá. Saludos y buena lectura!

---

El problema es que tienes una petición asíncrona mientras se dispara `Swal.fire`. Para poder enviar el valor de `resp` luego de la consulta, debes utilizar un callback.

```javascript
$.ajax({
  success: function(r){
    DespachadorRespuesta(r); // aquí se llama la alerta con la respuesta.
  }
});

function DespachadorRespuesta(respuesta){
  Swal.fire({ //https://sweetalert2.github.io/
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Actualización incidentes',
    text: respuesta +'aaaaaa' ,// cambié el nombre de tu variable
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    confirmButtonText: 'ACEPTAR',
    allowOutsideClick: true //cerrar popup al clickear fuera del este
  }).then((resultado) => {
    if (resultado.isConfirmed) {
      location.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

Si deseas concatenar una serie de respuestas puedes mantener la misma lógica y disparar la alerta en el último paso de su construcción, tal y como tienes, declarando una variable para el `scope` de `ajax` y actualizándola.

Comment: Tenias razón finalmente, lo que se me ocurrió para poder concatenar fue que en el each, se detectara cuando fuera la ultima pasada para así llamar la función de la alerta con todas las respuestas del ajax. Gracias.

Comment: Genial, que bien que lo resolviste. Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Como esta declarado esa variable resp vacío al inicio no te saldrá nada, lo que necesitas es retornarle un valor a esa variable cuando ejecutas el ajax.

```
success: function(r){
resp = resp + r;
console.log(resp);//aqui si se imprime
return resp;//RETORNAS EL VALOR NUEVO
},
```